# knockoutjs data bind of something doesn't exist yet

Tags: knockout.js

Lets say I have a list of items, and the data is created by mapping plugin, and it's normal that the list is empty. I would like to have a form that performs edit and create actions, which should bind to a single selected item.

```
<div id="appointment-modal" class="reveal-modal" data-bind="with: appointment">
    <form id="appointment-form" data-bind="submit: submit_appointment">
        <input type="text" name="name" data-bind="value: name"/>
        <textarea name="description" data-bind="value: description"></textarea>
        <input type="text" name="time" data-bind="value time" />
        <input type="text" name="address1" data-bind="value: address1"/>
        <input type="text" name="address2" data-bind="value: address2"/>
        <input type="text" name="phone" data-bind="value: phone"/>
        <input type="text" name="email" data-bind="value: email"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

The problem is, I get errors complaining about appointment is not defined:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: with: appointment
Message: appointment is not defined
```

I might be able to use the "if" binding to check if `appointment` exists, but I don't know how to cater for creation, ideally I would like to reuse the same form.

Came across this [link](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/betterList.html), I can just create a dummy obervable "appointment", but since appointment is dummy, the div renders nothing, this is not good particularly for creating new appointment item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have come up a workaround, which instead of defining an observable, define an observableArray()

In the template, instead of bind the observable like this:

```
<div data-bind="with: listing">
  <div data-bind="text: title">
</div>
```

You bind like looping through an array:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: listing">
  <div data-bind="text: title">
</div>
```

So the template won't complain about fields are not yet mapped.

To populate the listing into the template, just like this using mapping plugin:

```
vmodel.listing.removeAll();
vmodel.listing.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(listing_json));
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, you need to define the property, even if it's null ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PFGDN/) - this is what you're experiencing).  You just need to, as you've discovered, define the property with a null value (the default value for observables) and just add the appointment object to it later ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PFGDN/1/)).  This is perfectly acceptable.

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.appointment = ko.observable();// Don't set any value
}
```

This is one way to do a "late binding".  If later, you add some new html to the DOM, you can call `ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(myViewModel, $("#parentDiv")[0])`.  But in your particular case, I'd probably have the `self.appointment` property defined ahead of time.

Update:

Create an object with all the properties defined and bind it like this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PFGDN/2/).  Then when it's submitted, clear all the fields.

Comment: Hi, I actually tired this but my form is rendered nothing because appointment being null.

Comment: What exactly are you after?  Your question implies the problem is related to `appointment` not being defined as a property but that doesn't seem to be the case anymore.  If `appointment` is null, nothing should render, this is expected behavior, and when you set it later, KO will update the DOM.  Do you want the form to 'render' but no data filled in?

Comment: What I am after, as mentioned in the question, would like the form to show up when creating new appointments.

Comment: Gotcha, updated the answer.  You need to define an empty appointment object and bind it to the form.  When it's submitted, you do your validation checks, and after a successful PUT call to the server, clear the form afterwards (or do whatever else you need to do).

Comment: Thanks for the update, so there is no way for me to avoid declaring the model attributes before hand?

Comment: If there were no elements in your array to model after, how would your application be able to create the bindings w/out having defined your attributes? You'd at least have to always pass over a 'blank' and then rely on ko's mapping plugin [ko.mapping.fromJS] to create the properties for you.

Comment: Yeah, there's no way to bind 'anonymous' properties to the DOM.  KO needs a data object backing its bindings.  What you could do is, if you have a dynamic object on the server, you could pass the model to your view, loop through its properties, and set up your binding fields dynamically. Then on page load, create a dynamic 'Appointment' object using these property names to define those properties, and create your model that way.  But if you ask me, that seems like a lot more work than it's worth.

Comment: hmmm I guess I will just have to hardcode some data model then.